# Алгоритм индикации цифр на динамическом семисегментном индикаторе

Tags: vhdl

Как реализовать индикацию числа в шестнадцатиричном коде (0000…FFFF) на vhdl? Основа алгоритма управления  транзисторными ключами - цифровой автомат.

Comment: А в десятичном у вас уже реализовано?

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте. 
Реализуется через простой мультиплексор.
Код на картинке. Оригинал по ссылке [Hex-to-7seg-VHDL](http://appliedelectronicsengineering.blogspot.ru/2015/11/hex-to-7-segment-display-fpga.html)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]